# Modifying JAXB generating classes from XML and customizing JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

There is few elements in my XML/XSD like `<TestElement tc="222">SomeValue</TestElement>`. As per the XSD tc and its value belongs to another element which has just key value pair.

```
<xsd:element ref="TestElement" minOccurs="0" />
<xsd:element name="TestElement" type="SUBTYPE_CODES" />
<xsd:complexType name="SUBTYPE_CODES">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="tc" use="required" type="TRANS_MODE_CODES_TC" />
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

In this way by default JAXB has generated separate class for this element with two String key and value. 
JAXB generated element

```
@XmlElement(name = "TestElement")
 protected SUBTYPECODES testElement;
```

Attribute class:

```
@XmlType(name = "SUBTYPE_CODES", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class SUBTYPECODES {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "tc", required = true)
    protected BigInteger tc;
}
```

Now I have more than thousand classes for each type of attribute. And I am going to use these classes as entity classes for Hibernate.

I want to change it to in JAXB classes something like given below and get rid of all the attribute specific classes.

```
protected String testElementTC;
protected String testElementValue;
```

How can I declare above variables in JAXB generated classes without affecting marshalling/unmarshalling?